# apisauce (axios wrapper) - Can i handle the response error to write once and automatically called instead of manually add if else

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, axios, httpresponse

I have too many API to called in my project and I'm using [apisauce](https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce) to communicating into API

I've an example code :

```
api.get("myUrl")
.then((response)=>{
  console.log(response)
  if(response.ok && response.status == 200){
    //displaying data to screen
  } else{
    //display alert failed to call API
  }
})
```

for now I want to handle if the `authorization token is failed` I want to redirect to `login page`, but I don't want to add the code `authorization token is failed` to all of my `api` request

Is there a way to create code `else if(!response.ok && response.status == 401){redirectToLogin()}` once instead of add this code into all of my `API.get`?

Comment: Why not use interceptors?

Comment: at least the expected result is like what i need, it's fine, but i'm not used `interceptors` yet

Answer (score 0):

For our react-native app I create a class with own get, delete, put, update methods, which handles errors and then invoke apisauce.get e.t.c.

I use flow type annotations, but it'll be nicer using typescript for easily creating private methods.

```
 type ApiRequest = (url: string, payload?: Object) => Promise<ApiResponse>;

 export class Api {
      apiSauce: {
        get: ApiRequest,
        post: ApiRequest,
        put: ApiRequest,
        delete: ApiRequest,
      };

      constructor(baseURL: string) {
        this.apiSauce = apisauce.create({
          baseURL,
          headers: {
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          },
          timeout: 60 * 1000,
        });
      }

      _get = async (url: string, payload?: Object) => {
        const res = await this._handleResponse(this.apiSauce.get, { url, payload });
        return res;
      };

      _put = async (url: string, payload?: Object) => {
        const res = await this._handleResponse(this.apiSauce.put, { url, payload });
        return res;
      };

      _post = async (url: string, payload?: Object) => {
        const res = await this._handleResponse(this.apiSauce.post, { url, payload });
        return res;
      };

      _delete = async (url: string, payload?: Object) => {
        const res = await this._handleResponse(this.apiSauce.delete, { url, payload });
        return res;
      };


      _handleResponse = async (apiRequest: ApiRequest, params: ApiRequestParams): Promise<ApiResponse> => {
         const res = await apiRequest(params.url, params.payload);
         return this._handleError(res);
      };

      _handleError = (res: ApiResponse) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
            // **redirect to login page**
          }
          if (res.data && res.data.message) {
            showNotification(res.data.message);
          }
          showNotification(res.problem);
        }

        return res;
      };

      getUser = async (userId: string): Promise<User> => {
        const response = await this._get(`users/{userId}`);
        return transformUserApiResponse(response.data);
      };

}

const MyApi = new Api(BASE_URL);
```